# Kill Java proccess while running a while loop

Tags: java

I'm have a JFramePanel with two buttons that runs this code:

```
public void runProc (){

        while(true){

            System.out.println("Running...");
            PrintWriter outputStream = null;

            try {
                outputStream = new PrintWriter (FILENAME);
            } 

            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                try {
                    Process failedToWriteFile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(DIALOGBOX);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            outputStream.println("hello");
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("");

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } 

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Path d= Paths.get(FILENAME);

            try {
                Files.delete(d);
            } 

            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } 

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void killProc(){

        System.exit(0);

    }
```

When I press Start the code runs but when I press Stop it's not stopping
the start button remains clicked and the Stop button is not effective 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How should we ever know why your buttons are doing something? Don't you think we would need to see the code behind your buttons/panels to answer your questions? You think we wizards here?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one Thread that handles GUI actions like a click on a button. While this thread hasn't finished his work, the GUI is frozen and doesn't react to other inputs.

If I want a button to start a longer task, it should be done within an extra thread like a SwingWorker and only the start of this thread should be done within the GUI thread (e.g. the actionPerformed-method).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the start button is calling runProc directly which means it is running on the Event Dispatch thread.
This Thread is then stuck in a while(true) loop and is never returning to the application. I.e. the stop button never gets a chance to run.

Your start button should rather use SwingWorker and SwingUtilities to call the methods outside of the EDT and a boolean variable start and stop the thread vs System.exit(0)

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

    public class TestProc{

    boolean isRunning = false;

    public TestProc(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JButton b = new JButton("Start");

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

                    public Void doInBackground() {
                        if(!isRunning){
                            isRunning = true;
                            runProc();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        });

        JButton b1 = new JButton("End");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        killProc();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new JPanel());
        f.getContentPane().add(b);
        f.getContentPane().add(b1);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void runProc (){
        while(isRunning){
            System.out.println(".");
            try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void killProc(){
        isRunning = false;
        System.out.println("DEAD!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new TestProc();
    }
}
```